# How can I create a slanted trapezoid like navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I've struggling to create a trapezoid like navigation bar but I couldn't succeed. This is how it should look like:

[image: image description]

If anybody can at least point me to the right direction I would be very thankful.

EDIT: Found a solution. Here is the html

```
<ul class="slanted-tabs">
    <li>
      <a>Location</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Visit Types</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And SCSS

```
.slanted-tabs {
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1.0em 2.5em 0.1em;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1;
    a {
        &.active {
            background: none;
        }
    }
    &:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; 
        right: 0; 
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        border-bottom: none;
        background: #ddd;
        transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(2deg);
        transform-origin: bottom;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try this code by Lea Verou http://dabblet.com/gist/6867917

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way to get slanted sides to a CSS-styled element. But there are a few tricks you can utilize:

- Use Bitmap-images for the tabs or the tab sides. This is the "classic" way, the way the problem used to be solved. It also allows for even more complex tab sides.
- Use SVG-images, (see [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/svg-tabs-using-svg-shape-template/)) either inline or external. This has many of the advantages of Bitmap-images,and in addition to that, your page still scales
- Use rotated elements. Css allows for rotation of elements. You can draw [just about everything](https://www.bypeople.com/50-impressive-css-drawings/) this way. Somebody even designed a font this way. An example of using 3d transforms to create slanted tabs [can be found here](http://lea.verou.me/2013/10/slanted-tabs-with-css-3d-transforms/).

If you want quick-and-dirty, take the first option.